# importing data from csv - could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulties importing some data from a csv file.

**Input from csv file (extract):**

```
  Speed;A
  [rpm];[N.m]
  700;-72,556
  800;-58,9103
  900;-73,1678
  1000;-78,2272
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
inT = "test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(inT, sep = ";", decimal = ',')
print(df)
df = df.loc[1:]
df=df.astype(float)
ax = df.plot(x='Speed')
```

**Error:**
The decimal replace does not work and the following python error occurs

```
could not convert string to float: '-72,556'
```

**Desired Output:**

```
   Speed         A
0  700.0   -72.556
1  800.0  -58.9103
2  900.0  -73.1678
3  1000.0  -78.2272
```

Comment: which pandas version are you using?

Comment: The values are loaded as strings due to the second header line. If you `print(df.dtypes)` you'll see that both series are `object`

Comment: @mozway: Using 1.3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `skiprows=[1]` in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to skip the row 1, the conversion to float should be automatic:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = ';', decimal = ',', skiprows=[1])
```

output:

```
print(df)
     Speed        A
0      700 -72.5560
1      800 -58.9103
2      900 -73.1678
3     1000 -78.2272

print(df.dtypes)
  Speed      int64
A          float64
dtype: object
```

##### Why your code did not work

When reading the `"[rpm];[N.m]"` line, the csv parsers determines that the column(s) are strings, not floats. So the decimal specifier is simply ignored and the `-72,556` values remain as string, with the comma.